# Expo-Updates giving errors on ejected react native project, how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, react-native, babeljs

I am ejecting my react-native project from managed to bare flow due to needing WebRtc. However, after ejecting and going through the instruction in the docs, I build the client in Xcode and receive the error:

```
 com.facebook.react.Javascript (13): "expo-updates must be configured with a valid update URL or scope key"
```

I have installed expo-updates using npm install expo-updates and then npx pod-install just as the docs say.

```
Here is my package.json


    {
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "cypress-open": "cypress open",
    "cypress-run": "cypress run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.8.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^1.1.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.10.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.0.0",
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.9",
    "expo": "^39.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.6.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "expo-updates": "^0.3.5",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.12.2",
    "react-native": "~0.63.3",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.11.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1",
    "@cypress/snapshot": "^2.1.7",
    "cypress": "^6.0.1",
    "cypress-image-snapshot": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "api": "https://groups.blindlydate.com",
  "name": "BlindlyGroups",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

```
./app.json
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "client",
    "slug": "client",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "sdkVersion": "39.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "entryPoint": "./index.js",
    "icon": "./Assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./Assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "io.expo.ios"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./Assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "io.expo.android"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./Assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

```
   ./metro.config.js

    module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    assetPlugins: ["expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles"],
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Comment: I add to /ios/your-app-folder/Supporting/Expo.plist these to lines:
<key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
<string>https://example.com</string>

Answer (score 0):

If this error occur when running ios:
Add to /ios/your-app-name/Supporting/Expo.plist

```
<key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
<string>https://example.com</string>
```

For Android:
Add to /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
You will see related tags(meta) in the file, include this snippet there...

```
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https:example.com"/>
```